# Issue with finding the correct selector to bypass a Google Recaptcha

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, nightmare

First, I must say I'm very new to the idea of web scraping. I've learnt basic webscraping using request + BeautifulSoup and Scrappy in python. I have successfully been able to replicate what I learnt using python with javascript, with the help of [Nightmare](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nightmare) and cheerio.

I've been attempting to bypass a google recaptcha at [this site](https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/858/new-arrivals) using Nightmare's click action on the checkbox of the google recaptcha, and for all the different CSS selectors I tried with I keep getting an error saying that a selector by that name wasn't found.

My thought process is "If I can click on the recaptcha, I will be bypassing it so I just have to click on it" which is why I'm using the click action in Nightmare.

My objective is to bypass the google recaptcha and take a screenshot of the website.

Now I have 2 questions:

**Question 1: Am I just using wrong CSS selectors? What can I do to identify the correct selectors to bypass a google recaptcha?** If I am going with the wrong CSS selector, please provide the correct one(s).

**Question 2: Is there some anti-scraping mechanism preventing me from clicking on it? Is my thought process incorrect, if so why is it incorrect? How would I bypass this mechanism preventing me from reaching my objective?**

Here is the code I used, ofcourse I used other id based and class based selectors too

```
  const Nightmare = require("nightmare");
    const nightmare = Nightmare({
      show: false,
      frame: false,
      width: 1024,
      height: 1024
    });
    nightmare
      .goto("https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/858/new-arrivals")
      .click('div.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark')
      .screenshot("./2.png")
      .end(() => "done")
      .then(() => console.log("Finally over"));
```

Comment: "*If I can click on the recaptcha, I will be bypassing it*" I highly doubt that.

Comment: Yeah.. I kind of feel the same now, after actually trying it out

Comment: You need to solve the captcha. 2captcha.com has some examples, but you need to pay for the solves.

Comment: It's a checkbox type captcha, which is why I was going on about clicking it

Answer (score 0):

Recaptcha is preventing the automated solving of the captcha. What I am doing to workaround this issue is running Selenium with Pypeteer in a non headless mode, solve the captcha manually in the browser after it comes up one time and then have the process pick up from there and scrape whatever I need to.